# What is the point of (push,pop,shift and unshift) in loops?

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner at Javascript and I thought push is to add new item(s) to the end of an array but I can't figure out what is the point of (push,pop,shift and unshift) here.

```
var myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  myArray.push(i) //<-- Why we should use push here and what is the point?
};

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: *"I thought push is to add new item(s) to the end of an array*" That's exactly what the code is doing. Pushing `i` to the `myArray`. What's the confusion here?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the person who wrote the code? If this is from a book or tutorial, I assume the point is to show you what push does.

Comment: @Erfy Please search before you ask a question here.

Comment: You have answered the question yourself, "_I thought push is to add new item(s) to the end of an array_"

Comment: @GuyIncognito it is from a tutorial about how to use for loop, don't rush :D

Comment: @AshikPaul I searched but didn't found any explanation!

Comment: @adiga Thank you so much man. I was so confused because I'm beginner and only saw them in simple coding. You helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`i`, inside the loop, is your current index. Pushing it to `myArray` at each "revolution" will add the number to the array, and you'll essentially end up with an array that contains every index the for loop has been through, like so:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`.push`, `.pop`, `.shift` and `.unshift` are all great array methods to manipulate data inside arrays.

Here, on each loop of the for loop, you are pushing `i` into `myArray`. This should result in the array being built up as follows:

`[]`
`[0]`
`[0, 1]`
`[0, 1, 2]`
`[0, 1, 2, 3]`
`[0, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4]`

(it starts at 0 because you initialised `i` as 0)

You can do almost anything you like in for loops

There are plenty of other array methods you should be aware of, have a look here (list on the left hand side) for more info:

[Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thansk, appreciate your help.